# How can I change the background color of a complete section after clicking on one of it's child elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a personal project trying to match the below design:

I am on what I see as the hardest part. When clicking on one of the 6 different colored boxes, there should be further information popping up like below:

I am trying to first implement a background color change when the Facebook Ad Campaign box is clicked. When clicked, the background color of the whole container (which holds the 6 boxes) should change.

I believe jQuery is the right way to go about this but having tried the below it is not working:

```
$("#fbAdCampaigns").click(function(){
$(#container-parent").backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

Or, trying this to test if it changes the first out of the 6 boxes:

```
 $("#fbAdCampaigns").click(function(){
$("#fbAdCampaigns").css({ "background-color": "#ffe"});
})
```

Neither are working as intended as nothing happens.
Please see what I have done so far here:

https://codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzWyKv

Many thanks in advance for any assistance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

1. Delete your in-line `<script>` tags after the imports and move them to the JS section, which would be an external file in a local project.
2. You only need one `document.ready` function.
3. Instead of `.click` use `.on('click', function() ...)`
4. Instead of `.css('attribute': 'value')` use `.css('attribute', 'value')`

As a best practice, you should not use inline CSS and Javascript when you already have CSS and JS files.

Here's some working code that doesn't do exactly what you want, but should give you the way forward:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#menu").on('click', function() {
    $("#icon").toggleClass("fa-times");
  });

  $("#fbAdCampaigns").on('click', function(){
    $("#fbAdCampaigns").css("background-color", "#000000");
  });

});
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I have tried removing all inline scropt tags and placed all the js on the right hand side of codepen. However, neither click function for the menu bar icon change nor the background color change of the 6 boxes are working. Please advise on why this is the case? You can see what i've done here https://codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzWyKv

Comment: The menu click is not working because you took out the menu click function (see code in answer above). You changed from jQuery.css() to jQuery.toggleClass(), which needs to be called on a class, not an id. You still have inline styles competing with your CSS file. If you want to change the background of the entire 6-panel area as in your mock-ups, you need to target the div with the appropriate id or class, which in your case is `<section id="container-parent">`

Answer (score 0):

You're changing the color of the container, but it isnt visible because of the 6 boxes on top of it. Try something like this, which changes the color of each box when clicked:

https://codepen.io/aprouja1/pen/mYwEeX?editors=0010

```
function changeBackground(){
  const clickedColor = this.style.backgroundColor;
divs.forEach(div=>div.style.backgroundColor=clickedColor)
}
```

Comment: This is great thank you. How would you make it so after you click it again everything reverts back to the initial colors?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to the #fbAdCampaigns element to handle the CSS changes or use .css().

```
$("#fbAdCampaigns").on('click', function() {
  $("#fbAdCampaigns").addClass("bg-color");
});

$("#fbAdCampaigns").on('click', function() {
  $("#fbAdCampaigns").css("background-color", "#fff");
});
```

Using .addClass also means you can revert the change easily with .removeClass. Alternatively you could use toggleClass

```
$("#fbAdCampaigns").on('click', function() {
  $("#fbAdCampaigns").removeClass("bg-color");
});


$("#fbAdCampaigns").on('click', function() {
  $("#fbAdCampaigns").toggleClass("bg-color");
});
```

To access the entire container you can use the jQuery method .parent()

https://api.jquery.com/parent/

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/arwZZm

Comment: I have tried this just now - added a new class in the CSS i.e. .bg-color { background-color: blue } and the relevant jQuery but nothing happens when I click on it?https://codepen.io/JoyFulCoding/pen/EzWyKv

Comment: Your updated codepen is great thanks I now know how to apply it to all elements. However, the hamburger menu on the top right corner no longer changes to a cross when you click on it?